# Bulk delete WordPress posts with phpMyAdmin

Tags: posts, bulk, phpmyadmin

I have over 8,000 posts generated by wp-o-matic and I want to get rid of all of them.

I want to execute this query in phpMyAdmin. I just want to make sure this is safe to run and it's not wiping out my pages. This is the query:

```
DELETE FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE 'post_type' = 'post'
```

Thanks

Comment: These days it's nearly always better to use WP-CLI for tasks like this, see this solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/370322/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-range-of-posts-by-id-with-wp-cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join isn't that complex, but I wouldn't bother with it. Since you have a lot to remove a direct SQL query will run a LOT faster than WP.

However, we do need to keep track of the post ID numbers and remove the descendants and metadata.

Not tested / Make a backup / your risk etc. etc.

```
create temporary table `cull` (`post` int);

insert into cull select ID from wp_posts where my_criteria = 'my value';

delete from wp_posts where ID in ( select post from cull );
delete from wp_posts where post_parent in ( select post from cull );
-- done with temp table, cleanup metadata
delete from wp_postmeta where post_id not in ( select ID from wp_posts );
delete from wp_comments where comment_post_id not in ( select ID from wp_posts );
delete from wp_commentmeta where comment_id not in ( select comment_ID from wp_comments );
delete from wp_term_relationships where object_id not in ( select ID from wp_posts );
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to do this with `SQL`. There is post information is multiple tables. You will end up with orphan data scattered throughout the database. While it is possible to write the `JOIN`s you'd need to delete everything, the `SQL` could be complex.

Create a simple Loop and [use the Core to delete your posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post).

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);

$del = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($del->have_posts()) {
  $del->the_post();
  wp_delete_post( $post->ID, false ); 
}
```

Set the second argument to `wp_delete_post()` to `true` to bypass the "trash" and go straight to "permanently, irretrievably gone".

Comment: newbie here - where do i place this code to execute?

Comment: Hi. Sorry @vulgarbulgar. I haven't been on the sire much in quite awhile. Put this in any active theme or plugin and it should work. I usually have a throwaway plugin for this kind of tweaking code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sequence of the IDs to be deleted *(e.g. from 12001 to 23006)* and **YOU ARE SURE(!)** there is no post you'd like to keep, with and ID between the first/last IDs to be deleted.

> Example: a plugin--e.g. a sitemap plugin--generated thusands of posts and you know that all posts betweeen ID 12001 and 23006 should be deleted, you could run:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id in (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ID BETWEEN 12001 AND 23006);
```

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts where ID BETWEEN 12001 AND 23006;
```